# c# odbc update query doesnt work properly

Tags: c#, sql-update, odbc

Hi I'm having a lot of truble doing a program in c#

i have to connect to SQLANYWHERE 11 and do an update to a table

could u tell me where I'm wrong?

program go well until i reach the:
int number = wCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); line
the program doesnt crash but tables get not updated

```
        string dns = "Dsn=dattest;Uid=******;Pwd=******;";
        OdbcDataReader reader;
        OdbcCommand wCommand;
        ODBCClass dst1 = new ODBCClass(dns);
        queryins = "UPDATE dba.Sala_export_dati_macchina_produzione SET stato='p'";
        // +"WHERE id_prd_lav_ord_lav='"+ id_prd_lav_ord_lav + "'";
        wCommand = dst1.GetCommand(queryins);
        int number = wCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("executed "+ number);
```

this is the odbc class that i'm using

```
public class ODBCClass
    {

        OdbcConnection oConnection;
        OdbcCommand oCommand;

        public ODBCClass(string DataSourceName)
        {
            oConnection = new OdbcConnection(DataSourceName);

            try
            {
                oConnection.Open();

                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Connessione stabilita con il database " + DataSourceName);
            }

            catch (OdbcException caught)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(caught.Message);
            }
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            oConnection.Close();
        }

        public OdbcCommand GetCommand(string Query)
        {
            oCommand = new OdbcCommand
            {
                Connection = oConnection,
                CommandText = Query
            };

            return oCommand;

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            oConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

EDIT

just in case i've tried to change connection string with this pattern:

```
@"Driver={SQL Anywhere 11};DatabaseName=my_db_name;EngineName=my_server_name;uid=username;pwd=password;LINKs=tcpip(host=host_ip_address)"
```

and always the system gave me no error on connection in both cases

Comment: i have checked it with a select and column "stato"'s value doesn't change and number is equal to 0

Comment: If you run your query `UPDATE dba.Sala_export_dati_macchina_produzione SET stato='p'` manually, does it work?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (smallest possible code that we can copy and paste into a console app to repro the issue).

Comment: @mjwills i think that the first code snippet is what you are asking...

Comment: I suppose I was suggesting you get `ODBCClass` out of the mix, and make the smallest possible repro. Make sure it is in a console app, and you have run the code **in the console app** and seen it compile and (more importantly) not work (i.e. exhibits the problematic behaviour).

Comment: Are other database updates working? Or is it **just this one** that isn't working?

Comment: Please **try** another update to see whether it works. Also check whether `select` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys that was kinda strange.

Let me explain the whole thing. I was doing that program for a customer that asked a software which could link my mysql db and a sybase db of another company.

The problem was that the DBMS of that company when is opened on the server block all kind of external editing to the db with which is connected.

So select query worked regularly but update and insert were blocked by that client...
I've passed 4 day with a perfect working program but that company didn't told me this "little" thing.

So be aware of DBMS they are cruel.